# Good way to animate views inside some of RecyclerView's items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-viewholder

I have `RecyclerView` with `MyItemHolder`.
`MyItemHolder` contains `MyView` which can do animation.

1. How can I start animation of `MyView` for specific visible item in
   `RecyclerView` from `Activity` in which I have my `RecyclerView`?
2. How can I keep animation alive when user scrolled `RecyclerView` so that animated item has become invisible? For example, duration of
   `myView` animation is 1000ms. 500ms — `myView` has become
   invisible after scroll. 800ms — `myView` has become visible again
   and I want to see last 200ms of animation.

I hope that the question is clear.

Thank you very much in advance!